# Prevent "Would you like to open (URL)" dialog on iOS push notification deep linking

Tags: ios, onesignal, ios14, apple-app-site-associate, react-native-onesignal

I use deep links in push notifications (using OneSignal + React Native) to open specific parts of my app. Recently my users started to get the following confirmation when they tap the push notification (which wasn't the case before):

[image]

This is unacceptable from a UX perspective, and wasn't the case before (tapping the push notification used to launch the appropriate part of the app directly). The app opens anyway when the push is tapped, and the appropriate part in deep link is opened correctly if the user taps "Open", but of course the user shouldn't be confirming a deep link into the same app that the push is sent to. I've also got my Apple App Site Association file valid in `mydomain/.well-known` directory and validated using https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ as below (redacted my team ID and app name):

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "MY_TEAM_ID.com.myapp.myapp",
                "paths": [ "*" ],
                "components": [
                   {
                      "/": "/*",
                      "comment": "Matches any URL"
                   }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
       "apps": [ "MY_TEAM_ID.com.myapp.myapp" ]
    }
}
```

I've also have my applinks and associated domains set up correctly and exactly matching in entitlements. Why did I start getting this confirmation and how can I directly launch deep link without a confirmation? (I'm on iOS 14.4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with OneSignal React Native SDK which was fixed in v4.0.6.

Comment: Thanks Can! It worked when I updated it from 4.0.3 to 4.0.7

Comment: @İsmailŞener you are welcome, glad to see it helps!